# Does array contain data

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I am programming in Excel VBA.

I have a file where I open an explorer window and select a file or files and return the names of those files into an array.

I need to check if the array is filled or not. I've tried `if FileNames(1) <> "" Then` which works if there is something in the array. But when the array is empty I get an error of `type mismatch`. If I try `If FileNames <> False Then` it works when the array has nothing in it, but gives me the `type mismatch` error when there is something in the array. I have the array just as a normal variable like `Dim FileNames`, but I've tried `Dim FileNames() as String` too without success. Whether I select a file or not I get the `type mismatch` error. Here's the code I've got:

```
sub GetUserInfo()
    Dim FileNames

    FileNames = Select_File_Or_Files_Windows 'This opens the Explorer window and allows you to pick multiple files

    If FileNames(1) <> "" Then
        'Do something
    Else
        'Do the last thing
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I think [this](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/VBAArrays.htm) may help you. See `IsArrayAllocated` Function.

Comment: Would be helpful to show the code for the function `Select_File_Or_Files_Windows`, so we can see how it creates the return value

Comment: `Select_File_Or_Files_Windows` is almost definitely returning a non-string array or a non-array. That's the only thing that I've tried that will give a type mismatch - everything else will end up with things like subscript out of range or dimension mismatch. Double check the values in `Filenames` after it returns and make sure that all the values in it are strings.

Comment: @Mikegrann It does return all strings for the array. I had that part working before I starting needing to check if there were any filenames in the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

being it a Variant, try

```
If IsArray(FileNames) Then...
```